# Bash: local variables with same name

Tags: bash

I want to avoid the use of global variables to prevent unexpected behavior of a script, and I found that in bash there are local variables. By testing the local variables I found that:

This code works.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    local a=$1
    let a=$a+5
    let $2=a
}

boo() {
    local b
    foo 5 b
    echo "$b"
}

boo # Will print 10
```

But this other code doesn't work.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
foo() {
    local a=$1
    let a=$a+5
    let $2=a
}

boo() {
    local a
    foo 5 a
    echo "$a"
}

boo # Will print blank
```

Why is it so?

Then, even having local variables, am I forced to use diferent names for all my variables?

Then what I gain using local varaibles instead of global ones?

Comment: In the first case, the second `let` statement expands to `let b=a`, which changes the `b` from `boo`. In the second case, the second `let` statement expands to `let a=a`, which is a no-op.

Comment: I wouldn't change variables as side effects, I would print the result and then assign it with command substitution, like `b=$(foo 5)`.

Comment: `let b=a` is ok since boo's `b` is visible to its children foo. but the moment you create a local variable named `a` in foo, boo's `a` is not visible to foo anymore. I think it makes sense. By using local variables in functions (declared within curly braces) you're keeping the current execution environment clean. Just give a different name to variable, it shouldn't be so hard

Comment: I was seeing $2 as a "reference" or "pointer" to boo's `a` o `b`. By your comments, I understood that $2 is just a symbol that will be expanded to `a` or `b` in those cases, but if it is expanded to `a` and there is a local variable `a` in the child then that expanded `a` will be the same `a` that the child's local variable and not the parent's `a` local variable, and a child variable with the same name than a parent variable will always make the parent variable inaccessible. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, you did, that's the deal.